# How to get a specific video from a channel/playlist using the Youtube Data API?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, playlist

I was trying to get a specific video from a channel's uploads playlist. With specific I mean that I'd like to get, for instance, the 156th video from a playlist. As far as I know, the only way to do this is to request the first 50, use the nextPageToken to get the next 50 and keep doing this until I get to the 50 videos, which includes the 156th video. Even though I could implement this, it would take quite some bandwidth if I'd have to do this, especially if the channel has maybe thousands of videos and I need to get one of the last ones.

I tried searching for a way of setting part in such a way that I don't need to receive 'id' (which is AFAIK the smallest amount of data you can get from a video) from a video and instead only get the nextPageToken, but I can't find a way of doing this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Edc

Comment: How are you determining to get the 156th video? I assume you don't have  the video ID, but are there other filters you can use?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to find the 156th video of a playlist, meaning I have the id of the playlist and want to get the 156th item in the playlist. No worries though, I've found a suitable solution. If anyone has the same problem he/she can contact me :)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I **think** I found a solution. The nextPageTokens seem to be consistent during my testing, meaning the first nextPageToken will be the same every time as long as the parameters that affect the listing (like maxResults) is the same. So technically you'd only have to get one long playlist and save the nextPageTokens you get with that specific maxResults, and use those to get a specific page next time.